# Best type to store multidimensional data in for speed

Tags: powershell

I have a script that compares database links and runs test-path to check if it is exists, anything that doesn't is added to a custom object. For older clients, the amount of documents deleted from the file system but not the database is huge. So i am trying to speed this up a bit:

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
  $count = 10000
  $hashtablelistofitems = @{}
  for ($i=0; $i -le $count; $i++) 
  {
    $hashtablelistofitems.add("$i", "i'm a value")
  }
} | Select-Object -Property TotalMilliSeconds



Measure-Command -Expression {
  $count = 10000

  $array = @()
  $listofitems = "" | select key,value
  for ($x=0; $x -le $count; $x++) 
  {
    $listofitems.key = "$x"
    $listofitems.value = "i'm a value"
    $array += $listofitems
  }
} | Select-Object -Property TotalMilliSeconds



Measure-Command -Expression {
  $count = 10000

  $myitems = @()
  for ($x=0; $x -le $count; $x++) 
  {
    $myitems += @([pscustomobject]@{key=$x.path;ID="i'm a value"})
  }
} | Select-Object -Property TotalMilliSeconds
```

At the moment i am using the 3rd approach, the results of these commands are:

```
TotalMilliseconds
-----------------
          40.0566
        2609.2074
        3061.0848
```

So as you can see, i am using the slowest method and a hashtable is far faster than a custom object. My problem is, i am having issues piping the hashtable values to a reporting module like `Export-Excel` in a neat format to send to the clients.

Are there any other multidimensional datatypes i could use? or is there a way i can improve the speed of the custom object i am currently using?

Here is the code i am using to get the data:

```
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        if (!(Test-path $file.Path)) {
            $myitems += 
                @([pscustomobject]@{path=$file.path;ID=$file.ID;ObjectID=$file."Object ID";ObjectType=$file."Object Type"})
        }
        Write-Verbose "Processed :: $($file.path)"
    }
```

Then just piping `$myitems` to `export-excel`

Comment: Do you need to collect the results in an intermediate data structure?  As you found, appending to an array with `+=` is inefficient, but not buffering the entire results collection in memory before processing has benefits as well.  Something like `$files | Where-Object { !(Test-path $file.Path) } | Select-Object { # Create your [PSCustomObject] } | Export-Excel`.

Comment: This was what i was planning on doing, sending it all to Test-Path and creating an object from it. Problem is, due to the time this will take for larger databases i was planning on building a progress bar into it. Would that still be possible without a loop and a counter?

Comment: You could have a counter tracking how many files have been processed, but you won't know how many total files there are pending deletion from which to calculate the progress bar percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another solution to speed things up: using `System.Collections.ArraLyist`.

I've modified your third solution a little bit:

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
  $count = 10000

  $myitems = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  for ($x=0; $x -le $count; $x++) 
  {
    $myitems.add(@([pscustomobject]@{key=$x.path;ID="i'm a value"}))
  }
} | Select-Object -Property TotalMilliSeconds
```

Running all those solutions on my computer shows the following result:

```
TotalMilliseconds
-----------------
          35.9567
        2148.3292
        2408.9981
         151.4771
```

As you can see, it really is faster than using an ordinary PowerShell `ArrayList`.

`System.Collections.ArraLyist` Implements the IList interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

The reason why 3rd approach is slow is that array resizing is a costly operation. In .Net and thus in Powershell, an array has static size. When more elements are added, a new array is created for larger a size and all the elements are copied into it. This makes a lot of extra work in a loop.

Initializing the array into proper a size makes the loop a snap. Like so,

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
  $count = 10000

  # There's a -le, so count+1 is needed to contain all the values
  # Allocate large enough an array
  $myitems = @(0)*($count+1) 

  for ($x=0; $x -le $count; $x++) 
  {
    $myitems[$x] = @([pscustomobject]@{key=$x.path;ID="i'm a value"})
  }
} | Select-Object -Property TotalMilliSeconds
TotalMilliseconds
-----------------
     115,2909
```

The original version ran 2623,2247 ms on my system, so it's not (only) about different a computer.

When working with a huge number of operations, consider breaking those in manageable size of batches.